# Replacing folder icons

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We are setting up a photolibrary in SharePoint and would like to replace the brown folder icons with something more exciting and more relevant. Is this possible? Can it be done by someone with very limited IT skills? Many thanks.
C

Comment: Welcome to SharePoint SE!  Can you provide us with some more information? Like are you using On-Prem or Online (Office 365)? If On-Prem, what version of SharePoint are you using?

Comment: Also, could you specify what do you mean by "very limited IT skills"? If that person feels comfortable with CSS and/or JavaScript on normal web pages?

Answer (score 1):

In case of On Premise you can do this by

1. Replacing the existing icons with new ones. The impact will be across the web applications
2. Using JavaScript you can change this to your custom icon on the fly

In case of SharePoint Online you are left with only option of using JavaScript

That being said the person needs a bit of JavaScript coding skills to get it working.

Below is a snippet you can try

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('img[src$="folder.gif"]').each(function({
        $(this).attr('src','/siteassets/folder.png');}
    );
});
```

The code basically removes all IMG tags which has source set to `folder.gif` with a `folder.png` file that resides in the Site Assets Library.

Answer (score 1):

**THIS IS BAD PRACTICE**, but including it anyway.

OOTB SharePoint is using,  /_layouts/15/images/folder.gif?rev=23

Look on all the servers in your farm for:

C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft Shared\web server extensions\15\TEMPLATE\IMAGES

Backup/copy folder.gif, and you can replace **Folder.gif** with another 16x16 image. Do an iisreset after that.

Comment: Direct file system changes with no mention of backing up the file or noting that subsequent CUs could potentially revert this, sorry Mike, this just isn't good practice.

Comment: yeah i know... shame! shame! @chris-danity, you should only do this in extreme conditions, and of course back up your folder.gif. This is technically bad practice, but we'll let the user decide. Just rounding all the bases here. I'd definitely go with Amal's solution, but throwing another  (bad) idea out there for variety.